# How to make a fade black background in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I would like to put a fade black covering my image, just like this one, with a text, a fade background and then my image. I just want to know how to implement this fade. Thank you!

[image: Example image]

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @Zain yes, I solved this problem 2min after asking :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a **drawable file**, I'll name it *gradient_background* (you can set any name)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient 
       android:angle="90" 
       android:startColor="#000000"
       android:centerColor="#00000000" 
       android:endColor="#00000000"/>

</shape>
```

then inside your **target xml**, create a **View** like this one, look that inside it, we're setting the **background** as your drawable file. In this case is *gradient_background*

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="post_image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/post_image"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="post_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/post_image" />
```

**So it should look like this:**

[image: final]
**:)**

Answer (score 0):

First, Make bottom_transparent_gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="#64000000"
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Then, add that drawable as your view background in which you want to show the fade background effect.

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/bottom_transparent_gradient"/>
```

And that's it! You can see the result you wanted. :)